# Ubuntu 12.10 Fan overspeeding

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 leaving Win 7 licensed ver. But again as usual I need to fix so many issues.

This time fan is creating lots of noise. I was looking for the solution and found the below:

```sh
sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq < \
  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq
```

But I read that cpufreq is for cpu frequency. What to do now? I have already executed the command. 
What is the solution for my problem of fan sound in Ubuntu 12.10. In win 7, this is not the problem.

Comment: Just a note, I think Ubuntu 12.04 is the more stable version. It's what I run and what my serious Linux-head friends have suggested to me...not that it solves your immediate problem...but just a suggestion

Comment: This should be redirected to correct place! I posted it again here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63220/ubuntu-12-10-fan-overspeeding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for 
[fancontrol](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/fancontrol.8.html)

Comment: yes, I am looking for fancontrol

Comment: It looks very complex solution. But Thanks

Comment: Well... pwmconfig will automatically configure all that for you.

Comment: I saw that I do not have hardware sensor on my laptop to control that.